# subtract when clicked button php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a button, i want it every time i click the button it'll subtract from my credit on database (MySQL). i tried everything that already answered on another question but still unable to solved my problem.

here's my code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check" class="button_x" style="width:100px" >
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    func();
}
function func()
{
    $query = "UPDATE users SET user_credit = user_credit - 2";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
?>
```

if im not using the if function, it work! but it would subtract the credit when i click the sub menu as well. or should i add 'where' at my query?

thank you.

Comment: Show your form code, in particular your opening form tag.

Comment: and is not a php operator. it is &&

Comment: @NeilMasters Yes it is :)

Comment: @jon stirling do i really have to provide an 3v4l... oh. oh dear.

Comment: @NeilMasters Please, let me. https://3v4l.org/OZ8Sf :D

Comment: Thats just rubbing my nose it :D

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you are not actually doing a `POST`, your form is probably using `GET`.

Another thing is you don't really need to check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` at all. Try this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    func();
}
```

If the above works, then my assumption was correct, you'll either need to use `$_GET` or change your form to use `$_POST`.

You can change your form to use `$_POST` by adding `method="POST"` to your form element around your button.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check" class="button_x" style="width:100px">
</form>
```

---

If the above doesn't work, I suspect your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable is empty somehow (Could be a something with your sever), in which case, the following should work:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    func();
}
```

---

Another way you could do this is to not care if it's `POST` or `GET`, by doing it this way:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    func();
}
```

Comment: @JonStirling Because it's not PHP's syntax?

Comment: @Samuel Yes it is?

Comment: @JonStirling Is that valid syntax? I've never seen it in practice, but now looking at the manual it appears it is correct. Could possibly be `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` being empty maybe?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php same as `&&` but with different precedence I think?

Comment: @JonStirling yes you are right... It's valid logic... My bad

Comment: The OP didn't post `form` code, so the method could be `GET`

Comment: @D.Dimitrov could be... but at this point it is all but speculations.

Comment: @Samuel I agree it's all speculation, but that is really the only reasoning I can think of this would happen, unless it's an issue with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` being empty, but my answer would solve that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put it inside a `<form>` tag?
Like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check" class="button_x" style="width:100px">
</form>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    func();
}
function func()
{
    $query = "UPDATE users SET user_credit = user_credit - 2";    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure that the $conn variable you are using is accessible inside the function? It's difficult to tell since I can't see the rest of your code, but if $conn is created outside the function it will not be reachable from inside. A solution to this would be to either create it again inside the function or to pass it in as a parameter like such:

```
func($conn);

function func($conn)
{
    $query = "UPDATE users SET user_credit = user_credit - 2";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

[Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: I missed that part. I guess the code we see in func() is incomplete since this apparently works despite the scope issues.